# it is a good idea to use colors for citations in hard bound thesis(printed copy)

Tags: citations, thesis

Do you think it is a good idea to use colors for citations in the hard bound thesis(printed copy)?

I think it is a good idea to use colors to make citations more visible in the PDF files on the computer screen but not in the book.

Comment: I've never seen this before in a printed copy. In addition, a printed colour page might be more expensive than a page printed in greyscale.

Comment: Personal opinion here, but I'm not so sure that more visible citations are a good idea. I consider the text more important, and citations break its flow, like parentheses or footnotes. What are the arguments in favor of this?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: I usually see it when the citation is a hyperlink to the bibliography / references.  The color acts as a signal that "this is clickable" and shows you where to click.  I don't think the visibility itself is the point.

Answer (score 6):

I agree, don't use colors for citations or any other text in print.

Besides being potentially distracting or harder to read, it's often more expensive to print.

Comment: And harder to photocopy.